# Zen Coding (Selected Text) in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana, aptana3, emmet

How can I do zen-coding with selected text? I was able to do it in Aptana Studio 2 but now I can't do it Studio 3..

I can type p*3, select that and run 'Expand Abbreviation' -- that works. it gives me 3 sets of p tags.

But I can't select an existing text and do zen-coding on *that* text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using built-in Aptana plugin, which has limited features support. Try to install Zen Coding for Eclipse plugin: https://github.com/sergeche/eclipse-zencoding

This plugin features “Expand Abbreviation by Tab key” option, as well as expansion of selected text.

Comment: I made a clean install of Aptana Studio 3 and installed zen-coding using the instructions @ https://github.com/sergeche/eclipse-zencoding#readme . However, I don't see 'Zen-Coding' Commands anywhere in the menu. I looked first @ 'Commands' sub menu but it wasn't there. I also can't find 'zen coding' in Aptana's preferences. I know though that it was installed already since when I try to install it again, it said that 'All items are installed'

Comment: I should add that I restarted Aptana.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get this to work and just used Dreamweaver instead for Zen-Coding purposes. Thanks for the help anyway! :)